# Bluetooth 5.1 Angle of Arrival backward compatibility

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am currently designing a simple indoor location project to evaluate possibilities of Bluetooth 5.1 standard. The feature I would like to use is AoA (Angle of Arrival) introduced in Bluetooth 5.1.

According to the standard, AoA allows to measure position of a transmitting device (tx) by approximating the angle and measuring RSSI on a locator/receiver (rx). Since AoA is a feature newly implemented in 5.1, I understand that rx needs to support 5.1 Bluetooth standard. How about the transmitting device? What is the minimum version of Bluetooth it needs to support? Can I use 4.x BLE beacons (or Android/iOS devices simulating beacons) for this purpose?

Comment: Can you provide some code references regarding AoA for android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation uses an extended version of the advertisement data that contains a "Constant Tone Extension". Both devices need to support this feature in order to calculate the angle. So no you can not use old 4.x devices. Both devices must explicitly support this feature, and use it. Keep in mind that far from all Bluetooth 5.1 and 5.2 devices support this feature.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure - Bluetooth 5.0 is also not enough for transmitter? So in order to use either AoA or AoD, both devices NEED to support Bluetooth >=5.1, right?

Comment: Both devices must implement the AoA or AoD feature, which were first specified in Bluetooth 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experience BLE AOA, not BLE 5.1 Direction Finding, you can create a special BLE frame on a BLE 4.2+ device. It can mimic the CTE frame, but the receiver side also needs to be able to handle this frame. It is not part of the 5.1 Direction Finding standard although.

Comment: do you have more info about how you'd go about creating this special frame to mimic the CTE frame? do you mean you could implement a frame that effectively does the same thing, if you also create a receiver to handle this custom frame? or do you mean you could actually implement a custom frame that fully appears to be a cte frame from the receiver's point of view (and thus would work with standard BLE 5.1+ implementations expecting a standard CTE)?