# How to access Bluetooth 5.1 advanced positioning features AoA AoD in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone know how to access the new Bluetooth 5.1 accurate location features in Flutter? If I were to scan a Bluetooth 5.1 device, how could I use it's hardware 'Angle of Arrival', 'Angle of Departure' that everyone talks about to find it accurately in a smartphone app?

Comment: Hmm, I am not aware of any API provided by Android to do it. If yes, you need to write the flutter API by yourself. However, Wifi RTT is available as an API on Android...

Comment: Additional to what @Christopher said: Both devices, your smartphone and the device you are talking to, need to support AoA or AoD to make this work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62558985/7473793)). I'm not aware of any smartphone that supports the new feature (but they also do not advertise them so I could've missed that).